# How Eclipse download and store XSD external files?

Tags: eclipse, xsd

When I open XSD file in Eclipse( in XSD Editor), it download all `xsd:import`'s are contained in file. But if I don't have internet, editor cannot download, it's obvious. In preferences(`Window -> Preferences`) is `XML-> XML Catalog`. Is possible add my `xsd:import` (xsd files) to catalog and Eclipse will use it in offline mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add your xsd/dtd file to the catalog.

I did it like this (for test) and eclipse does not complain:

```
Entry element:    URI
Location:         C:\Users\me\Desktop\log4j.dtd
URI:              file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/log4j.dtd
Key type:         URI
Key:              http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd
```

I used the native URL in my log4j.xml afterwards

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
```

I suppose this should also work with xsd files.

This comes from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5001223/367285) from me.

Comment: Using this trick, validation is much faster in offline mode (0.1 second with the local XSD compared to 21 seconds without the XSD).