# In Log4j2, how do I associate an XML Schema with log4j2.xml?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I have been giving the new Log4j2 a go. It seems, from the [documentation on migration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html), that the XML Schema/DTD specification has been done away with.

That seems like a step backwards. Surely it should be possible to associate either an XML Schema or a DTD with my `log4j2.xml` to assist writing it and for validation. I haven't been able to find anything useful in the documentation, and neither have I found the XML Schema or DTD itself.

So: In Log4j2, how should I associate an XML Schema with `log4j2.xml`?

Comment: If you just want to avoid e.g. Eclipse's warning for the XML file, take a look at the following [answer to "No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27750701/828080) by @Pub.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10852980/592355.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to have a schema/DTD with log4j2. Recently I've written a custom appender, and to support the appender my `log4j2.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="ERROR" packages="package.same.as.custom.appender">
  <appenders>
    <CyclicBuffer name="CyclicBuffer" bufferSize="200">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%t] %c{1.} - %msg%n"/>
    </CyclicBuffer>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <root level="info">
      <appender-ref ref="CyclicBuffer"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

The important things to note are that I've got a completely custom `CyclicBuffer` element, and that it has a completely custom `bufferSize` attribute. Have a look at the documentation surrounding `@PluginFactory` and `@Plugin` for more detail.

Because of this customisation, I don't think that the XML can be validated via a standard, common XSD/DTD. Instead, I think you'll need to create your own XSD if you wish to validate the XML.

One important thing to note, is that in my XML I've got: `<configuration status="ERROR"`. When this is present log4j2 will output any errors associated with incorrect configuration at runtime. While not as convenient as XML validation, it is also very useful!

Hope this is of some help,
Muel.

Comment: I see. I'm not in a position to criticize the design of Log4j2, but I thought the whole point of XML was that it's easy to validate ... but anyway, thanks!

Comment: It is possible, the non-dynamic format with `<Appender type="CyclicBuffer">` works as well: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Strict_XML; [glory1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19407812/253468) elaborated on this 3 years ago.

Answer (score 27):

Works for me with eclipse:

```
<Configuration strict="true"
           xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config 
           https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/logging-log4j2/master/log4j-core/src/main/resources/Log4j-config.xsd">
```

or against tagged version:

```
<Configuration strict="true"
           xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config 
           https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/logging-log4j2/log4j-2.8.2/log4j-core/src/main/resources/Log4j-config.xsd">
```

Comment: Nice :-) Small suggestion: Use the tag for your Log4j 2 version, eg log4j-2.9-rc1, instead of the master branch. In case the XSD changes: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/logging-log4j2/log4j-2.9-rc1/log4j-core/src/main/resources/Log4j-config.xsd

Comment: Worked for me on Netbeans as well.

Answer (score 22):

Please re-read the Log4J2 documentation about **[XML configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XML)** and you'll find these 2 places:

> Log4j can be configured using two XML flavors; **concise** and **strict**. **The concise format** makes configuration very easy as the element names match the components they represent **however it cannot be validated with an XML schema**. For example, the ConsoleAppender is configured by declaring an XML element named Console under its parent appenders element. However, element and attribute names are are not case sensitive. In addition, attributes can either be specified as an XML attribute or as an XML element that has no attributes and has a text value.

and a little further:

> **Strict XML**. In addition to the concise XML format above, Log4j allows configurations to be specified in a more "normal" XML manner that **can be validated using an XML Schema**. This is accomplished by replacing the friendly element names above with their object type as shown below. For example, instead of the ConsoleAppender being configured using an element named Console it is instead configured as an appender element with a type attribute containing "Console".

So **if you want to use XML schema validation for Log4j2 then use only Strict XML format**.

Comment: where is the schema?

Comment: @BrunoJCM `log4j-core-2.6.2.jar/Log4j-config.xsd`, but I use it like this:
`<Configuration strict="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=logging-log4j2.git;a=blob_plain;f=log4j-core/src/main/resources/Log4j-config.xsd">`

Comment: Thanks, but after realizing that strict mode doesn't allow optional appender on Logger, I gave up on it..

Comment: BTW it seems the location provided is outdated... new one seems like ``https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/logging-log4j2/master/log4j-core/src/main/resources/Log4j-config.xsd``

Answer (score 12):

I cannot seem to find a reference to the XSD on the Log4J2 website, but if you download the for 2.0 beta 5, you'll find it contains a Log4J 2 schema (Log4J-V2.0.xsd) in the path core/src/main/resources.

As stated by Muel, it's quite possible to have custom appenders.  Because of this I believe that it would only work if you use strict="true" in the main configuration node.

See: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#ConfigurationSyntax

I've used the schema attribute to add this to the configuration and it seems to mostly work.

Here's an example:

```
<configuration name="testConfiguration"
    status="debug"
    strict="true"
    monitorInterval="30"
    schema="Log4J-V2.0.xsd">
```

I say "mostly" because one problem I've found it that even some documented valid attributes (e.g. monitorInterval) are missing from the XSD.

Hopefully with future releases an accurate XSD of the strict format will become available.

Hope this is of some help.

-Steve

**Updated:**
See [LOG4J2-170](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-170) regarding issue with XSD validation

Comment: And 3.5 years later that issue remains unresolved. This is why you don't choose libraries based upon their documentation.

Comment: @Dave that issue is outdated, yes, but 99% is validated correctly and you get content assist as well. The XSD is always available in `log4j-core-2.6.2.jar/Log4j-config.xsd`, you can always copy it out and add that attribute.

Comment: This also might be helpful: http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2016/08/log4j-2x-xsd-is-not-fully-descriptive.html