# How to define a global Layout for log4j2?

Tags: log4j2

We can define an appender and set it for multiple loggers by referencing it with `AppenderRef`.

So is it possible to have a global `Layout` and reference it in any appender we want?

Just like `AppenderRef` in an `Appender`, can we use `LayoutRef` in a `Layout`?

Something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Properties>
    <Property name="env">dev</Property>
    <Property name="app">MyApp</Property>
    <Property name="module">MyModule</Property>
    <Lots Of Other Properties/>
  </Properties>
  <Layouts>
    <JsonLayout name="MyJsonLayout" complete="false" compact="false">
      <KeyValuePair key="myKey" value="myValue" />
      <KeyValuePair key="app" value="${app}"/>
      <KeyValuePair key="module" value="${module}"/>
      <KeyValuePair key="env" value="${env}"/>
      <Lots Of Other reference to properties/>
    </JsonLayout>
  </Layouts>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="consoleJson" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <LayoutRef ref="MyJsonLayout"/>
    </Console>
    <Kafka name="kafkaJson" topic="myTopic">
      <LayoutRef ref="MyJsonLayout"/>       
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="class1" level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="kafkaJson"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="class2" level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="kafkaJson"/>
    </Logger>

    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="consoleJson"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
```

#### Why I need this?

I've certain properties set at the beginning of my `log4j2.xml` config file and I'm using those properties in the JsonLayout as you can see them named as `app`, `module`, etc. By defining a global Layout, I'll have the luxury to edit the `Properties` part only. Otherwise, I need to make my changes in all appenders because they will have their own Layout and all properties of the layouts will be the same. It will be inefficient to have to write the same layout to different appenders.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from looking at the XSD from here
[master branch of the Log4j-config.xsd](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/logging-log4j2/master/log4j-core/src/main/resources/Log4j-config.xsd)

there is nothing like this.  I would like to be wrong as I need it myself.

So if it is possible than it is not in the schema.

Did you open an issue to the developers? If yes please post a link I will upvote it too.

another relevant question is here [13904481](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904481/in-log4j2-how-do-i-associate-an-xml-schema-with-log4j2-xml)