# Error after importing a project into eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, hibernate

This is the warning that I have been getting.
**The file cannot be validated as the XML definition "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" that is specified as describing the syntax of the file cannot be located.**

The jars for hibernate are present.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Some times `eclipse` may failed to load that `DTD` file specified in the `XML file`.

In such cases you can `download` and set it manually.

Even though the below link specified as for log4j xml file.Follow the same procedure for `hibernate.cfg.xml`

[Eclipse: Referencing log4j.dtd in log4j.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000884/eclipse-referencing-log4j-dtd-in-log4j-xml)

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when eclipse cannot detect the hibernate libraries on the `.classpath`. Make sure that they are added to the correct project `.classpath`.

You might want to refresh the project in-order for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I am even getting this warning. **The file cannot be validated as the host "www.hibernate.org" is currently unreachable.** 
It is showing a warning at this line in hibernate.cfg.xml :    
 
` <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">`