# log4j.xml referenced file log4j.dtd contains errors

Tags: java, xml, apache, logging, log4j

We have a project contains ejbModule, there is a `log4j.xml` file located in `ejbModule META-INF` folder as below

[image]

On this log4j.xml file, initial start with a referenced dtd file from Apache server, format as below

[image]

Usually, this reference section works fine, but since yesterday it suddenly could not compile with and not able to deploy the `ejbModule` ear file onto weblogic middleware.

Showing error as below

```
Description Resource Path Location Type
Referenced file contains errors (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd).  For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..." log4j.xml   /TEST_EJB/ejbModule line 1  XML Problem
```

[image]

And then I visit the referenced file location from given url as
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd will observe issue as

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd
Line Number 27, Column 1:<!ELEMENT log4j:configuration (renderer*, appender*,plugin*, (category|logger)*,root?,
^
```

[image]

**Updates:**

Even changed format to following not able to fix the issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN"
"http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd"
[
    <!-- Directory to write the log files to -->
    <!ENTITY logDir "C:/.../logs">
]
>
```

[image]

I have checked the links as [**Eclipse: Referencing log4j.dtd in log4j.xml**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000884/eclipse-referencing-log4j-dtd-in-log4j-xml), actually we are using the same way to refer `log4j.dtd` file in his question(which declared as successful part, before failed maven part)

I have two questions:

(1) Is this problem happen on Apache side (not because of coding or local settings) ?

(2) Is there any way to fix the problem ? Fix locally ?

Thanks for given any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine, looks like this issue caused by broken of `log4j.dtd` file on Apache service, I download source file of `log4j.dtd` from this [**link**](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.liferay.portal/portal-impl/6.1.0/META-INF/log4j.dtd), and put it to the same folder of `META-INF` as below:
[image]

Refer to it in `log4j.xml` as relative path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM 
"log4j.dtd"
[
    <!-- Directory to write the log files to -->
    <!ENTITY logDir "C:/.../logs">
]
>
```

Then clean and compile the `ejbModule`, the issue is gone and able to deploy to weblogic middleware.

Answer (score 0):

use following code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC
 "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
```

Comment: thanks, but even changed to code given here, not able to fix, already update the question to notify this.