# Warning in log4j xml file

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
    <log4j:configuration>
```

In the second line of above code, i am getting the following warning :( 
 
*The file cannot be validated as the XML definition "<>\src\main\java\log4j.dtd (The system cannot find the file 
 specified)" that is specified as describing the syntax of the file cannot be located*
Someone please suggest the solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why is Log4j trying to find log4j.dtd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968934/why-is-log4j-trying-to-find-log4j-dtd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the file log4j.dtd in your source.

Just donwload the file [from here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CPANInternal/CPANInternal-108/Log-Log4perl/xml/log4j-1.2.dtd?txt) and put in `src\main\java\` of your project

Comment: i did this. but the warning is still there.

Comment: i changed "log4j.dtd" to "log4j-1.2.dtd". now warning has gone. thanks!

Comment: yeah you're right, obviously the name should be the same of the file